# Haskell Servant passing custom data to auth handler

Tags: database, haskell, authentication, pool, servant

I'm using custom monad (with reader) to easily pass data like DB pool to my handlers (before using custom monad I used to pass connection as fn argument).

This is how I've defined my custom monad :

```
newtype Controller a = Controller
    { runController :: ReaderT ServerEnvironment Handler a
    } deriving ( Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadReader ServerEnvironment, 
                 MonadError ServantErr, MonadIO )
```

This `ServerEnvironment` is just custom datatype I use to carry my data.

Problem is that for my `AuthHandler` I have to specifically use function with:

```
r -> Handler usr
```

as authentication handler, I can't use my custom handler which would be :

```
r -> Controller usr
```

and I also have no way to pass in my `ConnectionPool` because signature can't be :

```
ConnPool -> r -> Handler usr
```

**So, how does one pass extra data to authentication handler in servant without using global `IO` state?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `AuthHandler` you put into the context doesn't have to be defined at the top-level! Generally, you'll want to do it in `main` so you have access to the database connections etc. which you've created:

```
type API = 
  ... :<|> (AuthProtect "myProtection" :> ...) :<|> ...

type instance AuthServerData (AuthProtect "myProtection") = User

server :: ServerEnvironment -> Server API
server env = ...

setupEnv :: IO ServerEnvironment
setupEnv = ..

-- This is essentially a 'Controller'.
authenticate :: ServerEnvironment -> Handler User
authenticate conn = ...

main :: IO ()
main = do
  env <- setupEnv
  -- Now, because we have access to the env, we can turn our
  -- 'authenticate' into the right type before putting it
  -- in the context
  let ctx = authenticate env :. EmptyContext
  run 8080 $ serveWithContext myAPI (server conn) ctx
```

Comment: still, is it not possible to use custom monad for authentication handler?

Comment: It is - we could have given `authenticate` the signature `Controller User`, and then had `let ctx = runReader (runController authenticate) env :. EmptyContext`.

Comment: mmm.. yes, but than I have to pass env to both my auth context and my regular controllers. I'm using `enter (convertController env) serverRoutes` to convert my `Controllers` to `Handlers` if I wanted to use `State` in my stack than that state would be out of sync for Authentication handler and my regular handlers.

Comment: True, though you can use the `Request`s `Vault` (or an `IORef`) if you want to thread state from the authentication handler to the normal handler.

Comment: You can't use `State` in your handlers for sharing and modifying state from different handlers or from within the same handler but on 2 different requests: using `State` for handlers only lets you read/modify some state within one run of a given handler on a given request.

Regarding the question itself: there's nothing (yet) that lets one easily call `enter` once and have it be applied to both the auth context and the handlers. Those are two very separate things, the context might contain various kinds of stuffs, some of which we don't want to apply this transformation to.